# hsts deprecated The "includeSubdomain" paramter is deprecated

Tags: node.js, loopback, hsts

I have a loopback 3 application. When I start the application with `. node` I get this in my console.

```
hsts deprecated The "includeSubdomain" parameter is deprecated. Use "includeSubDomains" (with a capital D) instead. node_modules/loopback/lib/server-app.js:74:25
```

I searched in my node_modules folder, but there isn't a loopback folder. So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's due to the `helmet` config in `middleware.json`. Just open it, then find and replace `includeSubdomain` to `includeSubDomains`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same error too,
But just viewing on PM2 logs to see that.

Do you use Loopback with PM2 or inside a Docker container?

I dont have this error with running "NODE . "